# Limpiar src de imagen si está vacia en la BD

Tags: php, jquery, imagen

Estoy intentando limpiar la cadena SRC que debe de venir de la DB, pero siempre me pone esto

```
    <img class="imagenProducto" src="
">
```

He intentado con este código eliminar ese espacio o salto de línea o no se lo que trae en la DB

```
$imagen = preg_replace("/[\r\n|\n|\r]+/", PHP_EOL, $articulo[$i]['portada']);
```

Pero sigue haciendo lo mismo, necesito que se elimine eso, para pdoer yo añadir con jquery una manualmente, ya que me detecta como que tiene contenido. mi php es este:

```
echo "<div class='row'>";
    for($i=0; $i<count($articulo); $i++){

        $imagen = preg_replace("/[\r\n|\n|\r]+/", PHP_EOL, $articulo[$i]['portada']);



        echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";

            if(empty($articulo[$i]['portada']) || $articulo[$i]['portada'] == " "){
                echo "No hay imagen." ."<br/>" ;
            }else{
                echo "<img class='imagenProducto' src='".$imagen."'/>" . "<br/>";
            }

            $id = $articulo[$i]['id'];

            echo "<br/>";
            echo "<span> Titulo: ".$articulo[$i]["titulo"] ."</span>". "<br/>";
            echo "<span> Proveedor: ".$articulo[$i]["proveedor"] ."</span>". "<br/>";
            echo "<span> PN: " . $articulo[$i]["codigo"] . "</span>" . "<br/><br/>";
            echo "<span class='bg-danger text-white'> Costo: " . $articulo[$i]["costo"] . "</span>" . "<br/><br/>";
            echo "<span class='bg-danger text-white'> Stock: " . $articulo[$i]["stock"] . "</span>" . "<br/><br/>";
            echo "<a href='controladores/generarOfertaEmseel.php?id=$id'>
                    <button class='btn btn-success mb-5'>Crear Oferta EMSEEL</button>
                  </a>";
            echo "<a href='controladores/generarOfertaIntegra.php?id=$id'>
                    <button class='btn btn-success mb-5'>Crear Oferta Informatica</button>
                  </a>";
            
        echo "</div>";
    }
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas una expresión regular, la función [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.trim.php) elimina todos los caracteres de espacio, salto de línea y otros, al principio y al final de la cadena.

Aparte, estás "limpiando" el dato creando la variable `$imagen`, que es la que deberías usar en la comparación:

```
    // Eliminas caracteres no deseados al principio y final de la cadena
    $imagen = trim($articulo[$i]['portada']);
    echo "<div class='col-md-2'>";
        // Evalúas la variable que ya limpiaste
        if($imagen == ''){
            echo "No hay imagen." ."<br/>" ;
        }else{
            echo "<img class='imagenProducto' src='".$imagen."'/>" . "<br/>";
        }
```